# How to install AUCTeX on a reformatted Macbook and set up to create PDF?

Tags: auctex

I just reformatted my Macbook.  How can I install Emacs with AUCTeX on it, and set it up to compile to PDF?

Comment: Installing emacs is described on the emacs webpage: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html#macos Installing AucTeX is described on the AucTeX webpage: https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download.html If you have specific questions after looking there, you could post them as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Emacs and then adding the AucTeX package via Emacs's package manager is one step of it, but you also need a TeX distribution, eg. TeXLive or MacTeX (the latter causing a hairy additional manual configuration to work with Emacs since it is installed in a different way, so I'd recommend downloading the current TeXLive iso image from tug.org and using this).  Then, in Emacs, you need to configure the AucTeX package to use `pdflatex` or `xelatex` as command (via `M-x customize-group auctex`, and then entering „Tex command” and setting the appropriate file names) so that you always get PDFs as a result.